# What is the Interface Builder keyboard shortcut to rotate a window?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

In IB, I can rotate a window by pressing the "arrow button" at the top right of a window to see a view in landscape/portrait modes. What's the keyboard shortcut to toggle this action?

Comment: Inquiring minds want to know! +1 and starred.

Comment: I'm getting quite certain there is no keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one; not documented anyway. Go with the property change option, I think.

Answer (score 0):

command + arrow key

Comment: That's for iPhone Simulator, not Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

In IB press ⌘-1

Command-1

This will load view attributes. The orientation is the first element.